# Suggesting different templates when theming a node form

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

```
function posts_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
      'post_node_form' => array(
        'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
        'template' => VARIABLE,
      )
  );
}
```

This is the way of suggesting a template to render the 'post_node_form' in Drupal 6. BUT I want to get the node editing form from 2 different paths:

- via AJAX through drupal_get_form('post_node_form')
- via default node/add/post

If I replace "VARIABLE" depending on the path (or whatever other condition), it will not work because it seems? the name of the template is cached and you need to flush caches to refresh it.

Any solution of suggesting different form templates?

NOTE. This is not the case of node template, (then you can put the template suggestions in the preprocess hooks). It's about node FORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I answer my own question:

The key of the solution is the hook `preprocess_NAME_OF_MY_FORM` , that is executed every page load and can be in your module or your theme.

So in my case, I wrote in my "posts" module:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_theme().
 */
function posts_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {      
  return array(
      'post_node_form' => array(
        'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
        'template' => 'post-form-custom',

      )
  );
}

function posts_preprocess_post_node_form(&$vars) {   
   // I check the path to know if node_form is retrieve through normal way or ajax way.      
   if (check_plain(arg(0)) == 'node'){
      $vars['template_files'][] = 'post-form-default';
   }
}
```

I had in my module folder the files `post-form-custom.tpl.php` and `post-form-default.tpl.php`

Answer (score 0):

Add this function/or modify if exists into template.php of your theme:

```
function phptemplate_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  // ...
  $node = menu_get_object();
  if ($node->type == 'post') {
    $vars['template_files'][] = VARIABLE;
  } 
  // ...
}
```

Comment: via AJAX I call drupal_get_form and that doesn't go through preprocess_page hook :( Probably also because I didn't implement it through normal Drupal menu system